# Umask is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, umask

I have an odd problem with umask in ubuntu 14.04
I have added below line in  /etc/pam.d/common-session

session optional pam_umask.so

I have also edited  /etc/login.defs and change the UMASK line to

UMASK           022

But while checking in command line is is showing 002 .Can any one tell what went wrong here?

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Try asking in https://askubuntu.com/, https://serverfault.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ . If you have success, you can answer your own question here to help others.